# How to assign paragraph / character styles automatically in word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

Hi I've a 200 pg fully formatted word document. The person who had worked on it earlier had not applied any style to the whole document and he has done it manually. Though the formatting was done very neatly it has become my job to assign character/paragraph styles to each and every paragraph. Does any one know of a script which assigns character/paragraph styles automatically to the existing word 2010 document?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use Word VBA to deal with your issue.

What you should do is:

1. Find the style you want to replace with a style (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221467%28v=office.11%29.aspx) or [some tips](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm))
2. Apply style to the found selection (see this SO thread: [How do I apply a style to multiple selections in Word using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284867/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-multiple-selections-in-word-using-vba))

If you want to check the right style, you can record a macro and adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Find and Replace dialog to find text based on its format (e.g. Bold, Size 14) and replace it with a Style (e.g. Heading 2).

This article sums it up pretty well....
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/search-and-replace-specific-formatting-fonts-stylesetc-in-microsoft-word/

[image: findreplace]